# Android Retrofit Expected BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have problem with Retrofit.

**CryptoCompareClient.java**

```
public interface CryptoCompareClient {
@GET("/data/pricemulti")
Call<List<CryptoPrices>> multiCryptoPrices(@Query("fsyms") String crypto,
                                   @Query("tsyms") String currency);

@GET("/data/price")
Call<CryptoPrices> singleCryptoPrice(@Query("fsym") String crypto,
                                     @Query("tsyms") String currency);
}
```

**RESPONSE JSON:**
(https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LSK&tsyms=USD,EUR,PLN)

> {"BTC":{"USD":6731.55,"EUR":5716.11,"PLN":24359.79},"ETH":{"USD":244.41,"EUR":207.73,"PLN":905.73},"LSK":{"USD":3.42,"EUR":2.91,"PLN":12.49}}

**RetrofitInterface.java**

```
public class RetrofitInterface {
Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
private static final String CURRENCY="USD,EUR,PLN,BTC";
public void multiCrypto(String names){
    CryptoCompareClient client=retrofit.create(CryptoCompareClient.class);
    Call<List<CryptoPrices>> call=client.multiCryptoPrices(names,CURRENCY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CryptoPrices>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CryptoPrices>> call, Response<List<CryptoPrices>> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CryptoPrices>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MyCrypto", "fail retrof "+t);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Logcat**

> D/MyCrypto: fail retrof java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: There are no json arrays inside, just key value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Call<List<CryptoPrices>>` to `Call<Map<String,CryptoPrices>>`. The response is not a list, it’s a map of strings (like `”BTC”`) to data.

Answer (score 0):

Your API method:

```
@GET("/data/pricemulti")
Call<List<CryptoPrices>> multiCryptoPrices(@Query("fsyms") String crypto,
                               @Query("tsyms") String currency);
```

expects a list of `CryptoPrices` as an array `[...]` and you are providing an object `{...}`.

Good luck with your crypto-client!